# CDBCriteria for Custom Cgridview

Tags: yii, cgridview

I do not fully know yii framework. How to make CDbCriteria for cases like this?
I have a basic query code like this.

```
SELECT
jam_kerja.id,
jam_kerja.id_cabang,
jam_kerja.tgl_berlaku,
jam_kerja_detail.id_jam_kerja,
jam_kerja_detail.shift,
jam_kerja_detail.jamkerja,
jam_kerja_detail.jamistirahat
FROM
jam_kerja ,
jam_kerja_detail
WHERE
jam_kerja_detail.id_jam_kerja =  jam_kerja.id and  jam_kerja.id_cabang=5
```

Maybe there Yii friends who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = 't.id,t.id_cabang, t.tgl_berlaku, jd.id_jam_kerja, jd.shift ,jd.jamkerja,';

$criteria->join = 'INNER JOIN jam_kerja_detail jd ON t.id = jd.id_jam_kerja'; 

$criteria->addCondition('t.id_cabang=5'); // edited this line

//and now give this criteria to your model

$model = YourModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: Thank tinyByte. But in CGridView still does not show with this CDbCriteria. :) I paste your code in mymodel like this [link]http://pastebin.com/pHFiGkdA

Comment: Show error : CDbCommand gagal menjalankan statementSQL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'jam_kerja.id_cabang' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT t.id,t.id_cabang, t.tgl_berlaku, jd.id_jam_kerja, jd.shift ,jd.jamkerja FROM `jam_kerja` `t` INNER JOIN jam_kerja_detail jd ON t.id = jd.id_jam_kerja WHERE jam_kerja.id_cabang=1

Comment: it says column id_cabang is not in table id_cabang, if that's right I need to see you tables schema, criteria is fine

Comment: http://pastebin.com/efLY5950, this my table schema, 1. jam_kerja, and 2.jam_kerja_detail.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, it may be useful to other friends.

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->join='INNER JOIN jam_kerja t1 ON t1.id=t.id_jam_kerja';
$criteria->condition='t1.id_cabang='.$_GET['id'];
```

Comment: this is the same answer I gave to you! you just added the input as a variable. how this is different?